# What actually happens in the memory or background when we convert a simple no. or something to string?

Tags: python-3.x

```
4
str(4)
```

I just want to know about the difference between the raw number and the string number, and how the python interpreter converts this to C, then to machine code.

Answer (score 0):

if you call str(x) ..in this case, 4 ... 4 will become a string. Thus you get '4'

Comment: This isn't wrong, but the OP is asking for much more depth in what is going on under the hood of `str(x)` in the python interpreter as it converts this to C++ then C++ to machine code.

Answer (score 0):

**From the Python documentation:**

> The `str()` method returns the "informal" or nicely printable
>   representation of a given object.
>
> For strings, this returns the string itself.
>
> If encoding and errors parameter isn't provided, `str()` method
>   internally calls `__str__()` method of an object.
>
> If it cannot find the `__str__()` method, it instead calls repr(obj).
>
> The difference with `repr(object)` is that `str(object)` does not
>   always attempt to return a string that is acceptable to `eval();`
>
> Its goal is to return a printable string. If no argument is given it
>   returns the empty string, `''`.
>
> If the encoding and errors parameter is provided, the first parameter
>   (`object`) should be a bytes-like-object (`bytes` or `bytearray`).
>
> If the object is `bytes` or `bytearray`, the `str()` method internally
>   calls `bytes.decode(encoding, errors)`.
>
> Otherwise, it gets the bytes object in the buffer before calling the
>   `decode()` method.

See https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str for details

Comment: Please provide a link to your source when quoting external resources.

Answer (score 0):

The Python interpreter does not convert this to C, or to machine code. The Python *compiler* compiles it into Python bytecode which is then executed by the Python virtual machine (which is written in C and compiled to native code).

The bytecode for `str(4)` is the following:

```
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (str)
              2 LOAD_CONST               0 (4)
              4 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              6 RETURN_VALUE
```

So it loads the function object for `str` and the constant `4` and then calls the function object with that constant value as its argument.

Under the hood, the `str` function will then attempt to call an internal “to -string convertion function” which is also accessible using `__str__` on the int object. So you can say that `str(something)` will call `something.__str__()`.

The implementation of `__str__` depends on the object type, for integers, this just converts it into a decimal string representation of the int. Custom types may define their own `__str__` implementation that does something completely different.